# Sort Posts by Their Comment Counts, Then Created_at Date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I need help figuring out how to sort my posts by the number of comments they have. Whenever multiple posts have the same number of comments, it will sort by most recent. I'm also trying to figure out if I should do this in the model or the controller.

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @feed = Post.find(:all, :order => "created_at ASC")
        @posts = Post.includes(:comments).order("comments.size ASC, created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(1)
   end
```

I'm using the kaminari gem for paging. I'll provide anything else that will help to answer this question.

Comment: Certainly not the controller. If you had a counter cache this'd be trivialer.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure I understand your second statement.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Comment: after doing this, how do I go about setting up the sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks in part to Dave Newton for providing a resource for me to work off of. I added the counter cache to keep a running count of the total amount of columns each post has. This is working so far.

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true, :counter_cache => true
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.order("comments_count, created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(1)
    end
end
```

**migration**

```
class AddCommentCounter < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
    add_column :posts, :comments_count, :integer, :null => false, :default => 0

    Post.reset_column_information
    Post.all.each do |p|
      p.update_attribute :comments_count, p.comments.length
    end
    end

    def self.down
    remove_column :posts, :comments_count
    end
end
```

This is working for me so far to sort by total comments and then by most recently created. Here is the railscasts link: [railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)